# WI-FI problems in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on a Sony SVP laptop. It detects my WI-FI network but when I try to connect, it does not work. I tried to connect via iwconfig, but when I try to set the essid i get the following error message: 
'Error for wireless request "SET ESSID" (8B1A) :
   SET failed on device wlp1s0 ; operation not permitted'
When I used 16.04 on the same laptop the WI-FI connection worked without any problem.
I know I am an early user of 18.04 but there must be some solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use systemd instead of network manager.
I used vi to create this file: /etc/netplan/03-wireless.yaml:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
         "the SSID":
            password: "the password"
(the SSID and the password shall be the actual SSID and password)
I created the run time config file and applied the config:
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
then I stopped and disabled network manager:
sudo systemctl stop network-manager
sudo systemctl disable network-manager
then I enabled and started systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
with the command networkctl I checked the status:
networkctl
and got this response:
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 wlp1s0           wlan               routable    configured

2 links listed.
after this i restarted the PC but I don't think that was necessary.